# How to get task name inside task in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using gulp-plumber + gulp-notify and want to put task name in gulp-notify as a title.
following is the code i wrote, thanks in advance.

```
gulp.task('SOMETASK', function() {
    return gulp.src(sourcePaths)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError({
            message: "<%= error.message %>",
            title: "I WANT TO PUT TASK NAME HERE"
        })}))
        // omitted below

});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```js
gulp.Gulp.prototype.__runTask = gulp.Gulp.prototype._runTask;
gulp.Gulp.prototype._runTask = function(task) {
  this.currentTask = task;
  this.__runTask(task);
}

gulp.task("someTask", function(){
  console.log( this.currentTask.name );
}
```

Comment: Is this changed? I get undefined on currentTask

Comment: @JimmyRare - It works if you watch the scope of the `currentTask` variable. If you set `var currentTask;` before this block and then change `this.currentTask` to `currentTask` in both places, it works fine. This code is expected to be within the scope of another object (hence the `this` reference).

Comment: doesn't work in gulp 4.0.0

Answer (score 9):

```
gulp.task('SOMETASK',function() {
    console.log('Task name:', this.seq.slice(-1)[0]) // Task name: SOMETASK
})
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work for all cases, namely nested cases.

Comment: This gets the first task name that started the process 'default'

Comment: It returns first task that will be executed after resolving all dependencies, and NOT CURRENT task.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monkey-patch Gulp, the following will work with Gulp version `3.9.0`:

```
var _gulpStart = gulp.Gulp.prototype.start;

var _runTask = gulp.Gulp.prototype._runTask;

gulp.Gulp.prototype.start = function (taskName) {
    this.currentStartTaskName = taskName;

    _gulpStart.apply(this, arguments);
};

gulp.Gulp.prototype._runTask = function (task) {
    this.currentRunTaskName = task.name;

    _runTask.apply(this, arguments);
};

gulp.task('jscs', function () {
    console.log('this.currentStartTaskName: ' + this.currentStartTaskName);
    console.log('this.currentRunTaskName: ' + this.currentRunTaskName);
});

gulp.task('jshint', function () {
    console.log('this.currentStartTaskName: ' + this.currentStartTaskName);
    console.log('this.currentRunTaskName: ' + this.currentRunTaskName);
});

gulp.task('build', ['jshint', 'jscs']);
```

Running `gulp build` will yield the following console output:

> c:\project>gulp build
>   [16:38:54] Using gulpfile c:\project\gulpfile.js
>   [16:38:54] Starting 'jshint'...
>   this.currentStartTaskName: build
>   this.currentRunTaskName: jshint
>   [16:38:54] Finished 'jshint' after 244 μs
>   [16:38:54] Starting 'jscs'...
>   this.currentStartTaskName: build
>   this.currentRunTaskName: jscs
>   [16:38:54] Finished 'jscs' after 152 μs
>   [16:38:54] Starting 'build'...
>   [16:38:54] Finished 'build' after 3.54 μs

Comment: This added useful information about the difference between the start task and the run task.

Answer (score 0):

```
let aCallerName = (new Error().stack.match(/ at [^(]+ /g)).map(s => s.replace(/(?: at | )/g,''));
console.log( aCallerName );
```

maybe aCallerName[0] or aCallerName[1]....

Answer (score -3):

Define the task name outside of the callback and reference it where needed.

```
var taskName = 'SOMETASK';

gulp.task(taskName, function() {
    return gulp.src(sourcePaths)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: notify.onError({
            message: "<%= error.message %>",
            title: taskName
        })}));
});
```

Comment: This doesn't help if it is nested... say we have `compile`, `watch`, `dev`, and `production` tasks.  `dev == [compile, watch]`, `production == [compile]`.  if task name is dev, then compile actually does some extra sourcemap stuff