# How to get root task name when gulp started

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm using gulp and want to print out and highlight **root** task name, that has been passed right from process arguments.

```
gulp sometaskname
```

This solution with [wrapping gulp constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161903/how-to-get-task-name-inside-task-in-gulp) gives me task name for each invoked task.

```
var runTask = Gulp.Gulp.prototype._runTask;
Gulp.Gulp.prototype._runTask = function(task) {
    GUtil.log(`Project task ${task.name} has started`);
    return runTask.call(this, task);
}
```

How do I get or detect the root one? Maybe from `process.argv`?

Comment: Have you tried `process.argv`? Because that seems like it would work.

Comment: It is too complicated. Arguments could swap around, it will be additional logic. I believe it possible to extract it somehow from gulp.